# Unity - C# - Power up a shot before firing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to launch a projectile which is simple enough using the UI Button's onClick property but what I also want to allow the player to do is charge up their shot. I have it working on the keyboard by using Input.GetButton("Fire") then I add Fire to the input manager and for the key I choose space. But what I'm trying to do now is add the same functionality to a virtual button for touch screen players. The problem is onClick can't check if the button is continuously pressed it can only be called once. So for that I'm trying to use the IPointer Up and Down Handlers in the button's script like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FireButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public bool buttonPressed;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        buttonPressed = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        buttonPressed = false;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

The problem is there seems to be an infinite loop in my logic for the tank script. As soon as the Update() function is called and the if statement below for fire button.buttonPressed is true for some reason it loops there and doesn't continue. Here's the following code (I commented out the logic for the keyboard input):

```
    using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TankShooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int m_PlayerNumber = 1;              // Used to identify the different players.
    public Rigidbody m_Shell;                   // Prefab of the shell.
    public Transform m_FireTransform;           // A child of the tank where the shells are spawned.
    public Slider m_AimSlider;                  // A child of the tank that displays the current launch force.
    public AudioSource m_ShootingAudio;         // Reference to the audio source used to play the shooting audio. NB: different to the movement audio source.
    public AudioClip m_ChargingClip;            // Audio that plays when each shot is charging up.
    public AudioClip m_FireClip;                // Audio that plays when each shot is fired.
    public float m_MinLaunchForce = 15f;        // The force given to the shell if the fire button is not held.
    public float m_MaxLaunchForce = 30f;        // The force given to the shell if the fire button is held for the max charge time.
    public float m_MaxChargeTime = 0.75f;       // How long the shell can charge for before it is fired at max force.
    FireButton firebutton;

    private string m_FireButton;                // The input axis that is used for launching shells.
    private float m_CurrentLaunchForce;         // The force that will be given to the shell when the fire button is released.
    private float m_ChargeSpeed;                // How fast the launch force increases, based on the max charge time.
    private bool m_Fired;                       // Whether or not the shell has been launched with this button press.

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // When the tank is turned on, reset the launch force and the UI
        m_CurrentLaunchForce = m_MinLaunchForce;
        m_AimSlider.value = m_MinLaunchForce;
    }


    public void Start()
    {
        firebutton = FindObjectOfType<FireButton>(); 
        // The fire axis is based on the player number.
        m_FireButton = "Fire" + m_PlayerNumber;
        // The rate that the launch force charges up is the range of possible forces by the max charge time.
        m_ChargeSpeed = (m_MaxLaunchForce - m_MinLaunchForce) / m_MaxChargeTime;
    }


    public void Update()
    {
        // The slider should have a default value of the minimum launch force.
        m_AimSlider.value = m_MinLaunchForce;

        // If the max force has been exceeded and the shell hasn't yet been launched...
        if(m_CurrentLaunchForce >= m_MaxLaunchForce && !m_Fired)
        {
            // ... use the max force and launch the shell.
            m_CurrentLaunchForce = m_MaxLaunchForce;
            Fire(); 
        }

        // Otherwise, if the fire button has just started being pressed...
        //else if(Input.GetButtonDown(m_FireButton))
        **//there is an infinite loop here needs fixing**
        else if (firebutton.buttonPressed)
        {
            Debug.Log("Test1 " + firebutton.buttonPressed);
            // ... reset the fired flag and reset the launch force.
            m_Fired = false;
            m_CurrentLaunchForce = m_MinLaunchForce;

            // Change the clip to the charging clip and start it playing.
            m_ShootingAudio.clip = m_ChargingClip;
            m_ShootingAudio.Play();
        }
        // Otherwise, if the fire button is being held and the shell hasn't been launched yet...
        //else if(Input.GetButton(m_FireButton) && !m_Fired)
        else if (firebutton.buttonPressed && !m_Fired)
        {
            Debug.Log("Test2 " + firebutton.buttonPressed);
            // Increment the launch force and update the slider.
            m_CurrentLaunchForce += m_ChargeSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            m_AimSlider.value = m_CurrentLaunchForce;
        }
        // Otherwise, if the fire button is released and the shell hasn't been launched yet...
        //else if(Input.GetButtonUp(m_FireButton) && !m_Fired)
        else if (firebutton.buttonPressed && !m_Fired)
        {
            Debug.Log("Test3 " + firebutton.buttonPressed);
            // ... launch the shell.
            Fire();
        }
    }


    public void Fire()
    {
        // Set the fired flag so Fire is only called once.
        m_Fired = true;

        // Create an instance of the shell and store a reference to it's rigidbody.
        Rigidbody shellInstance =
            Instantiate(m_Shell, m_FireTransform.position, m_FireTransform.rotation) as Rigidbody;

        // Set the shell's velocity to the launch force in the fire position's forward direction.
        shellInstance.velocity = m_CurrentLaunchForce * m_FireTransform.forward; ;

        // Change the clip to the firing clip and play it.
        m_ShootingAudio.clip = m_FireClip;
        m_ShootingAudio.Play();

        // Reset the launch force.  This is a precaution in case of missing button events.
        m_CurrentLaunchForce = m_MinLaunchForce;
    }
}
```

Also if you think there's an easier way to do this by using the input manager or some other way please feel free to share. Happy to change all this logic and try something else, been working on it for 13 hours now. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working! Dropped the whole UIButton approach and went with Input.touches

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see a fire rate logic which stops infinite shots. You can define a fire rate so it do not fire infinite logic might be

```
float fireRate = 0.25f;
float lastFireTime; // Must be global

if(Time.time - lastFireTime> fireRate)
{
  Fire();
  lastFireTime = Time.time;
}
```

End you may use Object Pool pattern instead of Instantiate for performance issues.

```
 Rigidbody shellInstance =
            Instantiate(m_Shell, m_FireTransform.position, m_FireTransform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
```

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the issue since I mentioned it was working fine with the keyboard. I got it working though, dropped the UIButton approach and went with Input.touches